# pyodbc, way to create and insert into a redshift table in one step

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I would ultimately like a build a script that
- 1. logs me into my redshift cluster
- 2. run a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statement
- 3. recreates the table
- 4. inserts data from a Pandas DataFrame object into the table

I can do it in 2 scripts - one that accomplishes steps 1-3 and then a 2d that accomplishes step 4. I was wondering if this can be done in one script. The following script, I try to use 2 cursors to accomplish this fact - but with no luck.

```
import pyodbc 
import getpass
import pandas as pd
server = server name 
database = db
user = getpass.getuser() 
pwd = getpass.getpass("User Name : %s" % user) 
port = port
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Amazon Redshift (x64)};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+user+';PWD='+pwd+';Port='+port+'')
cursor1 = cnxn.cursor()
cursor1.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS billtest2; CREATE TABLE billtest2 (symbols varchar(15), leverages int);")
cursor2 = cnxn.cursor()
# Insert DataFrame recrds one by one.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO billtest2 ([symbols],[leverages]) values(?,?)", row['symbols'], row['leverages'])
    cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

I have anonymised the connections, but the connection works - its simply the fact that I want to create and insert a table that is seemingly not working.

I am new to Python and would appreciate any further guidance here

Comment: Upon further work - this script does work........ but to insert even a 4x2 dataframe, it takes 10+ minutes. What are some ways I could speed this up? I have looked at sqlalchemy - but cannot get it to connect to redshift. executemany() does not speed this process along. Is there something basic I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried SQLAlchemy.

Or Amazon Redshift dialect for SQLAlchemy in your case.

```
From sqlalchemy import create_engine
Import pandas as pd
conn = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://username@host.amazonaws.com:5439/database')
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.to_sql('your_table',conn,index = False,if_exists = 'replace')
```

Before all this you may need to install [pip install sqlalchemy-redshift](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-redshift/).

How to install packages? -> [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).

Also you can explore to_sql more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).